# Add Static directory to Mojo Lite App

Tags: perl, mojolicious

Hell all,

I am trying to add a shared static directory to my Mojo Lite app but this does not seem to do the trick.

```
use Mojolicious::Lite;
use Mojolicious::Static;

# Documentation browser under "/perldoc"
plugin 'PODRenderer';

my $static = Mojolicious::Static->new;

push @{$static->paths}, '/my/path;
```

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 4):

You may add an absolute path as you do in your answer:

```
push @{app->static->paths}, '/my/abs/path';
```

you may also add a path relative to your app's home folder (this is how [the default is setup](https://github.com/kraih/mojo/blob/master/lib/Mojolicious.pm#L66)):

```
push @{app->static->paths}, app->home->rel_dir('my/rel/path');
```

The default is to have a folder called `public` in your app's home path. If you do this, the app will use it out-of-the-box. [Read more here](http://mojolicio.us/perldoc/Mojolicious/Lite#Static_files).

Comment: Maybe it is more secure to overwrite the default if you don't need it? I did it like this (maybe there is more elegant syntax, but `->` is still experimental afaik): `${app->static->paths}[0] = $public_dir;`

Comment: How is `->` experimental? `app->static->paths->[0] = $public_dir;` would work to replace the default. If you wanted to be even more sure that the new directory is the only on you could use `app->static->paths([$public_dir]);`. That said, the OP said "add" so all I did was add.

Comment: `rel_dir` has been renamed to `rel_file`

Answer (score 3):

This works:

```
my $static = app->static();

push @{$static->paths}, '/my/path';
```